# LoadLibrary from another DLL

Tags: windows, dll, path, loadlibrary

The DLL lookup path, as described [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is:

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Which brings up the following doubt:

Suppose I have an executable in some directory, say: `c:\execdir\myexe.exe` and it loads a DLL that's found in `PATH` and is located in `c:\dlldir\mydll.dll`. Now, suppose `mydll.dll` tries to load another DLL with `LoadLibrary`. Which directory will be looked at first - `c:\dlldir` or `c:\execdir`?

I think that the lookup rules quoted above say it's going to be `c:\execdir` because that's allegedly "the directory where the executable module for the current process is located", but it would be nice to get a confirmation from another source.

**EDIT:** Also, is `c:\dlldir\` looked at *at all*? After all, it's neither where the .exe is located, nor the "current directory" (if that is meant in the general sense).

P.S. I'm interested in both Windows XP and 7.

Comment: I don't understand what you're confused about after reading the docs. It seems pretty clear to me. Why would loading a second DLL change the path lookup sequence?

Comment: @Cody: because it's the second DLL that's doing the loading and not the .exe - the .exe isn't even aware of that 2nd DLL which is being loaded from the first

Comment: @Hans: thanks, I edited with another relevant question

Comment: c:\dlldir is implicitly looked at.  Otherwise the DLL would never be found.  Only two of the 5 rules could apply: PATH or current dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the executable directory first and it was realised [this could lead to a security vulnerability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919712%28VS.85%29.aspx) under certain circumstances. There is advice on that page for ensuring your application is not compromised via this mechanism.

Comment: So, `c:\dlldir` is never looked at, because it's neither "where the executable is located" nor "the current directory"?

Comment: @Eli If it isn't on the PATH, isn't the current directory or a special system directory or the directory of the original executable (let's say it is actually `c:\dlldir` rather than `c:\windows\system32` for example) then no, it won't be.